# What does init(staff: String...) mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

Sorry if this is a terribly basic question but what does the `...` mean used in this context? I know `1...` refers to 1 and everything after it in an array but I am still confused.

[image: Code Screenshot]

Comment: That's called a variadic parameter. See the [official language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) for more info on them.

Comment: Oh ok thank you, was proper hard to search ... on google.